# Excel formula: How to refer a cell by its column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I change my excel formula if I need to replace direct reference to the cell by the column name of this cell? For example, instead of

```
SUM(A1:B1)
```

I want to use something like

```
SUM({Column1}:{Column2})
```

I know about structured reference, but I can not convert my excel dataset into named table.
Do I have any options?

Comment: How have you assigned a name to your column ??

Comment: Well, I have no special assignment of a name to the column. One cell has a string with the name and values are under that cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the `column name` is the content of the header row for that column.

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to sum part of the row based on certain months, say between Feb and Jun.  In **B6** enter *Feb* and in **C6** enter *Jun* and in **D6** enter:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A2:L2,MATCH(B6,A1:L1,0)):INDEX(A2:L2,MATCH(C6,A1:L1,0)))
```

[image]

So by changing **B6** and **C6** we can change the part of the second row we are summing.

**EDIT#1:**

1. If we re-arrange the headers, the formula should adapt to the re-arrangement
2. The formula I posted was plain-vanilla.  It should work on old versions of Excel as well as the current version.  I am using the US Locale.  You may need to check the spelling of functions and may need to use a **;** rather than a **,** as the field separator character.

Comment: Strange, but excel says the formula is invalid. It seems to be something with MATCH(). But anyway, does your formula let me change the place of the column and get the same result? In example, we rename May to June and vice versa - will the formala return the same result?

Comment: @Ramzes  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be what I looked for.

Comment: I replaced commas with ';' and formula started to work

Answer (score 0):

You can also name the "columns". You can do this by selecting the value including the header row and going to Formulas > Create from Selection or Ctrl + Shift + F3 and selecting only the Top row option.

[image: Create Names from Selection]

Once done, you can create formulas using the header names instead of cell references.